# BIZTALK Uncaught exception

Tags: biztalk

I made a simple change in orchestration mapping and overwrite the dll in biztalk server. while running the application i get the below error. I'm not sure for each change we should sign the assembly(pfx). Please help.

> Uncaught exception (see the 'inner exception' below) has suspended an instance of service 'ORCHESTRATIONS.SHIPMENT_OSDOrche(292017c3-4497-cb97-ed96-e71be2951766)'.
>   The service instance will remain suspended until administratively resumed or terminated. 
>   If resumed the instance will continue from its last persisted state and may re-throw the same unexpected exception.
>   InstanceId: cd854c34-d326-4e22-9d7b-4a03bc8ec53a
>   Shape name: Listen_1
>   ShapeId: 377372ab-e98d-4f18-a6d7-0f8c249dcc67
>   Exception thrown from: segment 1, progress 3
>   Inner exception: Received unexpected message type 'INTERNAL_SCHEMAS.OSDFFSchema, INTERNAL_SCHEMAS, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=41a686c84f24a990' does not match expected type 'INTERNAL_SCHEMAS.OSDFFSchema, INTERNAL_SCHEMAS, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=664d619652e0365d'.
>
> Exception type: UnexpectedMessageTypeException
>   Source: Microsoft.XLANGs.Engine
>   Target Site: Void _verifyPublisherSchema()
>   The following is a stack trace that id

Answer (score 1):

Received unexpected message type 'INTERNAL_SCHEMAS.OSDFFSchema, INTERNAL_SCHEMAS, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=**41a686c84f24a990'** does not match expected type 'INTERNAL_SCHEMAS.OSDFFSchema, INTERNAL_SCHEMAS, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=**664d619652e0365d'**.

The message coming from the Port/Orchestration has a different .Net type than what is configured on the Orchestration Receive Port.

So, you have to update one so they match.

Comment: In particular it looks like the SNK changed on the project/DLL containing the schema.   When you say "I'm not sure for each change we should sign the assembly with a Strong Name Key.  The answer is Yes you need to sign it, but no, you should not use a new one each time but use the existing one.